# Can't resolve symbol toJson

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I'm using json4s in a play project, and I'm also using a library called [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) which generates Scala source from your build definitions.

Now, in the sbt-buildinfo library the say you need to add some line of code: `buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.ToJson` so you can use `.toJson`, but from some reason I can use `.toJson`.

this is how I do it:

```
import _root_.util.{AuthenticatedAction}
import buildinfo.BuildInfo
import com.google.inject.Inject
import org.json4s.BuildInfo
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

class AppInfo @Inject()(implicit configuration: Configuration) extends Controller {

  def appVerion = AuthenticatedAction {

    Ok(BuildInfo.toJson)
  }
```

but the `import buildinfo.BuildInfo` stays gray....so it looks like I'm not using it. I refreshed the build.sbt and all, what could it be?

Comment: Have you tried to compile it with sbt?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos yes, im getting and error says `value toJson is not a member of object org.json4s.BuildInfo`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple imports to a BuildInfo object. org.json4s.BuildInfo will probably shadow your buildInfo.BuildInfo import and therefore, it does not have the required member. Try writing out the entire package name that you need:

```
Ok(buildinfo.BuildInfo.toJson)
```